# How do I change the contents of a CSS element after a :hover pseudo-element activates using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have 2 boxes, one box that is red, and when my mouse hover overs it the box turns red.  The other box is blue, and when my mouse hovers over the box it turns blue.

What I want to have happen is that when my mouse hovers over box 1 the box turns blue AND box 2 turns red.  (Same idea with Box 2 but switch the colors

Here is the code that I tried already, I know that the issue is with the JavaScript but I don't understand why the JavaScript isn't working

```js
const outlineOne = document.querySelector('.outlineOne');
const outlineOneHover = window.getComputedStyle(outlineOne, ':hover');
const outlineTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('outlineTwo')
if (outlineOneHover.style.background = blue) {
  outlineTwo[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
```

```css
body {
  background: #2F2F2F
}

.outlineOne,
.outlineTwo {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

.outlineTwo {
  background: blue;
}

.outlineOne {
  background: red;
}

.outlineOne:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.outlineTwo:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="outlineOne"></div>
  <div class="outlineTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `if (outlineOneHover.style.background == "blue")`. (single = is assignment not comparison, and unquoted `blue` is an undefined variable.)

Comment: (Although that won't get you the whole way there, because getComputedStyle doesn't return a style object, and background colors won't necessarily be returned in that string form anyway (I get `rgb(255, 0, 0)`); you'd be better off setting and reading a classname that sets the color instead of reading the color directly)

Comment: JavaScript only runs on page load, it is not going to run on hover of the elements

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Have a div that wraps both `outlineOne` and `outlineTwo` and have a `:hover` selector on that, and then no JavaScript is needed (like your `parent` div in your example)

```css
.parent:hover .outlineOne {
    background: blue;
}

.parent:hover .outlineTwo {
    background: red;
}
```

2. Add a CSS class instead of adding `:hover` via JavaScript (so like `.outlineOne.addedClass { background: blue; }`, and listen for a `mouseover` event in JavaScript.

Technically you're not supposed to manually add a `:hover` to an element manually because it's a [trusted event](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events) that should be user-activated.

Comment: Please don't make people looking for an answer go to another site to find code. Instead, use a Stack Snippet (icon has `<>` on it in the toolbar) to create a runnable example here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a single class on both objects on mouseover and mouseout.

```js
const outlineOne = document.querySelector('.outlineOne');
const outlineTwo = document.querySelector('.outlineTwo');

function changeBG(){
    outlineOne.classList.toggle("active");
    outlineTwo.classList.toggle("active");
}


outlineOne.addEventListener("mouseover",changeBG);
outlineTwo.addEventListener("mouseover",changeBG);

outlineOne.addEventListener("mouseout",changeBG);
outlineTwo.addEventListener("mouseout",changeBG);
```

```css
body {
  background: #2F2F2F
}

.outlineOne,
.outlineTwo {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

.outlineTwo {
  background: blue;
}

.outlineOne {
  background: red;
}

.outlineOne.active {
  background: blue;
}

.outlineTwo.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="outlineOne"></div>
  <div class="outlineTwo"></div>
</div>
```